# Getting Exception Index 50 requested, with a size of 50

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am getting exception while fetching data from database. I am trying to get value of `column index 1` from this line of code `String ques=c.getString(1);`

this is the code where i am calling database class and trying to fetch database,

```
try{
   c=db.getText(Integer.toString(subid));
   if(c==null)
    return;

    //if(c.getCount()> 0)
    //{
    //int max=c.getCount();
    //int min=0;

    Random rn = new Random();       
    int randomNum =  rn.nextInt(max-1) + rowid;
    c.moveToPosition(randomNum);

    String ques=c.getString(1);
    tv.setText(ques+" ");

    cans=c.getString(2);
    shuffleArray(ans);
    int[] a = new int[4];
    int j=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ans.length; i++)
        {
          a[j]=ans[i];
          j++;
        }
     ans1=c.getString(a[0]);
     ans2=c.getString(a[1]);
     ans3=c.getString(a[2]);
     ans4=c.getString(a[3]);
     rb1.setText(ans1);
     rb2.setText(ans2);
     rb3.setText(ans3);
     rb4.setText(ans4);
    }

   catch(Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage()+"exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Snap shot of my database content,

[image]

And this is my database class,

```
public Cursor getText(String subId) throws SQLException //here it'll get all rows of subId=1 or whatever the value of subId
 {
  Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
        KEY_id, KEY_ques, KEY_correctans, KEY_wrongans1,KEY_wrongans2, KEY_wrongans3}, 
        KEY_subjectid + "=" +  " '" + subId + "' " , null,null,null, null,null);
if (mCursor != null) 
{
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
}
return mCursor;

}
```

As my above details and code, When the value of `subId is 1` then it is fetching all the content from the database of `subId 1` without any Exception but when i am passing the value of `subId=2` then it give `CursorIndexOutOfBound: Index 50 requested, with a size of 50` Exception
And when i am passing `subId=3` then i am getting `Index 49 requested, with a size of 49`
Is there any problem in Random number generator or what ?

Actually i am not able to get whats the problem here.

I need help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try generating your random number this way: (I'm assuming c is a Cursor)

```
int randomNum =  rowid + (rn.nextInt() % (c.getCount() - rowid));
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ok let me check and by the way I want to generate random number between the value of variable rowid (which will be as minimum value) and the value of `c.getCount` (which will be as maximum value)

Comment: ok, edited with what you requested. the problem before was that when you were adding the rowid, your result was going beyond the maximum size

Comment: Yeah thanks you are right but there is one problem also I dont want to repeat any value. So, what to do for that ?

Comment: in that case, you'd need to rethink several things. A good idea would be to load all the questions into an arraylist, then randomly remove one from the ArrayList and display it. Another option would be to delete rows from the db after you display the answer, another would be to alter the query with ID NOT IN (... List of displayed ids...). It really depends on how your overall code works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use space in query " = " actually your column name become "KEY_subjectid=" which is wrong 




 KEY_subjectid + " =" +  " '" + subId + "' " , null,null,null, null,null);
```